# 3rd party subscribtion integratgion - I'd like to give free premium subscribtion to my customers

Tags: spotify

I'd like to allow my customers to select as a reward a 1/3 month premium subscription to spotify.
What are the API integration options with spotify.
Cannot find it on their developers page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public API endpoint that allows a third-party application to create Spotify Premium subscriptions.